# Installing FPDF on Windows Azure

Tags: php, windows, azure, configuration, fpdf

I've been trying to install FPDF (fpdf.org) on Windows Azure. I have already succeeded with a local server (XAMPP) and everything works.

Now, when I try to install on Windows Azure using WebMatrix, nothing happens.

Here's what I've done :

I uploaded the FPDF files on the website folder. Then I created a main page (index.php) and wrote a simple example using FPDF.

```
<?php
require('../[FPDF folder]/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I don't think that the code is wrong (I tested with my local server XAMPP and it worked), however maybe I forgot to configure something on the Windows Azure configuration page.

Someone suggested that I had to do stuff with the "App settings" in the configure page; however I have no idea what I should put there regarding FPDF.

Anyone knows how to fix my problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of you code? Do you see anything? Do you see the correct output of `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: The output is a blank page. It is supposed to be a PDF.

Comment: But can you make sure that PHP is correctly interpreted?

Comment: Do you mean the code? The code should works, I tested in a local server. If you mean that Windows Azure can "read" PHP, it does, since I have other pages that uses PHP.

Comment: I am just wondering whether it is general PHP problem or a particular problem of FPDF. Did you try to substitute your code with `phpinfo()` on this particular page?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write

```
require('[FPDF folder]/fpdf.php');
```

in the above and try your program one more time.

Answer (score -1):

If you work on a localhost with some program such as "Xampp" and you create a folder with a name such as "*fpdf*" in the "*htdocs*" directory and your Project is "*PHP_PDF*" then you can use the below syntax:

```
include '../fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

If your "fpdf" folder is in your Project then use the following syntax:

```
include 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

If you work with a host-server on the Internet and you want set the "fpdf" folder out of your project for all of your Projects, then you should use the following syntax:

```
include 'www/../fpdf/fpdf.php';
```